# Method that returning anonymous object

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have code parts like that:

```
var @object =
    new
    {
        val = "SUCCESS",

        stuff = new
        {
            stuff1 = model.Stuff1,
            stuff2 = model.Stuff2
        }
    };
return Json(@object, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


var @object =
    new
    {
        val = "SUCCESS"
    };
return Json(@object, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

var @object =
    new
    {
        val = "ERROR",
        details = "Details"
    };  
return Json(@object, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

For me it is looking like kind of repetitive code that should be fixed.

I want to refactor that code so I can have something like that:

```
var @object = GetResult("SUCCESS", object myobj)
return Json(@object, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

What is the best practice of doing this?

Comment: You cannot return anonymous objects. Create one class and pass its object

Comment: @NitinVarpe You can return anonymous object, but you have to do it from method with return type set to `object` or `dynamic` and you loose type safety and intellisense support.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek yep as stated here http://tomasp.net/blog/cannot-return-anonymous-type-from-method.aspx/

Comment: I don't think you've thought this thru. Each of the `@object` you're creating are different. You can't get them all returned from the one `GetResult` method. What is the underlying need you're trying to cover?

Comment: @Enigmativity i have lots of places in the code with repetitive `@var @object = {bla bla}` constructions. I just want to reduce the repetitive multilevel code blocks with more simple ones.

Comment: @sreginogemoh - But it's not repetitive. The code between the `{` & `}` differs in each of the cases you presented. It's unique code.

Comment: @Enigmativity it's repetitive for me that's why I want to generalize it is somehow.

Comment: @sreginogemoh - I think the reason you're not getting much in the way of a good answer is that you're trying to generalize not unique code. You might need to go one deeper on your abstraction to solve this one.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're interested in generating properties to anonymous types and assigning values to those properies in runtime.

There's a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/799033/1074311) that shows you how to dynamically create classes but it seems like you will have to work pretty hard to get where you want.

Why not generate JSON strings from the different type of objects and the merge it to one JSON string?

```
       string val = "SUCCESS";


        var stuff = new
        {
            stuff1 = "some string",
            stuff2 = "4324"
        };


        string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(
            new {val, stuff}
            );

{"val":"SUCCESS","stuff":{"stuff1":"some string","stuff2":"4324"}}
```